# How to return result of two SQL queries in one cursor in PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a column A which displays values corresponding to the input Date `SYSDATE`  . I want to bifurcate that column into two parts such that one part displays the data corresponding to `SYSDATE` and the other part displays data corresponding to `SYSDATE-1` i.e. previous day .

Now the issue is that output columns are same for both the parts,its just the change in the processing of the query where one part takes input Date `SYSDATE` and other takes input `SYSDATE-1` .

I am stuck at the implementation of this requirement .

> Select A, B,C from Table -- Generalised query , now Column A has to be
>   split into two columns A1 , A2 ,Issue is how to display A1,A2 .

I have no clue of how to proceed .

Comment: Hey Radha, Can you please show what you have tried? the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a self join here:

```
SELECT
    t1.value,
    t2.value,
    t1.dt,
    t2.dt
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN yourTable t2
    ON t2.dt = t1.dt - 1
WHERE
    t1.dt >= TRUNC(SYSDATE);
```

This would pair up records from today only to corresponding records at the same time one day earlier.

Comment: Can you please explain the last condition : t1.dt >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)

Comment: Sure, this is just saying that `dt` has to occur on or after _midnight_ of the current date.  So, my result set would only include records where the first column is from today (and the second column the same points in time, one day earlier).